# Any jstree plugin for more customized and with better performance?

Tags: jquery-ui, jstree

In my web application, I am in the need to use jstree structure , so i researched about that jstree plugin but i didnt get right plugin ,

My requirement is , There is a form if i fill and submit it, first parent node is to be created and if selected the parent to add child node ..........

customizing sorting order, drag and drop.

Suggest best plugin if any,

```
 My question is whether there is any plugin best suits me or i may have to write new one?
```

Answer (score 0):

`jsTree 1.0-rc3` this plugin works fine and it is open source.

**Documentation**: http://jstree.com/